# Calibration of the first ammeter

Tags: electromagnetism

Lets say I have a ammeter(Digital or analog) that I want to calibrate . I can use another good ammeter to calibrate it .But in the early days, for the **1st** ammeter that was ever created , there was no other ammeter that could have been used to calibrate it.So my question is , how was the 1st ammeter even calibrated ?

Comment: Might be a better fit to [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Maybe you should look up how the Ampere and the Coulomb originally were _defined._ E.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere#History

Comment: Bootstrapping calibrations for, well, anything, was an interesting yet long and frustrating process.

Comment: I saw two different but equivalent definitions , A force definition and silver nitrite definition.Were these definition for 1 ampere used to calibrate the 1st ammeter? I mean ,did they had to sit down with a solution of silver nitrite and calibrate there first ammeter so that it would  give correct current reading?

Comment: @Prithubiswas they probably hadn't decided on a unit when they made the first ammeter. In fact they probably didn't know what they were measuring.